# Application manifest working on android, iPhone, firefox, opera, but not on iPad

Tags: ipad, html, offlineapps, offline-caching, manifest.cache

I'm having trouble getting a real simple html5 cache manifest to work on the iPad. 
It does however work on all other devices and browsers I've tested.

Are there any bugs in the iPad safari implementation or other limitations to the iPad or am I missing something ?

I'll include the relevant source files.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="example.appcache">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

example.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2010-06-18:v2

# Explicitly cached 'master entries'.
CACHE:
index.html
style.css

# Resources that require the user to be online.
NETWORK:
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read that on iPad the manifest file must be named "cache.manifest" and that you must specify it as a relative path like `<html manifest="cache.manifest">` and *not* something like 
 `<html manifest="/foo/bar/cache.manifest">`.  So, if it's working in everything else but just no in the iPad, check/try those two things.